# I didn't understand Regex on PHP.

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to clean all special characters from the string with regex code, so far I have did this code

```
$data = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/s', '', $nickname);
```

But this code cleans everything including spaces, I want to allow space and - sign on the string, so what should I exactly add in there? I am sorry if it is an easy question but my English is not really good and I couldn't find any resources in my main language. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Try [a-zA-Z0-9\s-] The \s will allow all whitespace (including tabs and such); to only allow a "spacebar" space, use a literal space in the regex instead. The - sign needs to be last in the square brackets, otherwise it is interpreted as a range, like in 0-9.

Comment: @m69 the `s` here is a modifier, but it doesn't have context here since the `.` is not being used. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: I am confused so will it be like this with the dot? $data = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/s\.', '', $nickname);

Comment: why can't my nickname be **++%X** ?

Comment: The `s` modifier is so the `.` includes newlines which by default it doesn't. Your regex doesn't use the `.`. From the manual, `a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded`

Comment: @LeBleu I highly recommend reading an introductory article on Regex. Most of the questions you're asking either here or in the provided answer are very clearly explained in almost every Regex guide you could find. If you provided your language, we could probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: @chris85 I was talking about the \s inside the range, not the s after the regex.

Comment: @m69 there is no `\s` in the character class, only `/s` after; maybe there was an edit

Comment: There was an \s in the suggestion in my comment, to which you responded.

Comment: So hello, how can I also not allow # and $ signs?

Comment: This is getting repetitive.

Comment: Nevermind. Someone else helped already.

Answer (score 2):

`$data = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/s', '', $nickname);`

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 .-]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jIg4irSk1hoeNvI8)

Comment: Dots are special, they match every character. You have to escape it with a `\.`

Comment: $data = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/s\.', '', $nickname); 

So will it look like this?

Comment: You actually don't have to escape the . within a group either.

Comment: I am confused so will it be like this? 
$data = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/s\.', '', $nickname);

Comment: Everything inside the `[]` is a set of what you're trying to match. In this case, you're looking for anything that is not one of the things inside that `[]` (because of the `^`). So if you want to allow `.`, put the `.` inside the `[]`

Comment: Thank you a lot for explaining, Jess! So I guess in total I'll have this.

$data = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -.]/s\', '', $nickname);

Comment: I don't know why you have an extra \ at the end

Comment: So hello, how can I also not allow # and $ signs?

Comment: Right now you're not. You said you wanted to ONLY allow a-z . and -

Comment: Now I need to make replace # to nothing as well, I realized # making problems on my codes. :(

Comment: It already will. `[^a-zA-Z0-9 .-]` is matching # and $ fine for me,

Comment: var datanew = data.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -.]/g, "");

Oh, I used this code also on Javascript and it is allowing sharp sign as far as I can see. Maybe there can be done something for Javascript? Sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: I mean I don't want to allow sharp sign

Comment: Move the . from the end to before the -. I tested it and the one I posted will MATCH on the #, which in your code will REPLACE it.

Comment: [^a-zA-Z0-9 .-]

![Regular expression visualization](https://www.debuggex.com/i/jIg4irSk1hoeNvI8.png)

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jIg4irSk1hoeNvI8)

Comment: Thank you a lot for everything! Works like a charm!

Comment: Okay I fixed it now, ty! :)

Comment: So Jess, I find out what causing errors on my javascript. I guesss that's because Space in beginning/the end and Some Double Spaces, could you tell me how can I delete Space in beginning/end on string and double spaces? I'd be so glad.